# Sysadmin rights to local administrator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How I can give the `sys_admin` rights to the local administrator for the SQL Server 2014 database while I installed it using the domain admin account, not local administrator account? Below is the requirement of a manual.

> SQL Server installation
>
> During the installation of AlarmInsight
>   components it is required to use local Administrator login. The SQL
>   Server Installation can also be done with local Administrator login by
>   giving required access rights. If another login is used to install SQL
>   Server, the local Administrator has to be given sys_admin rights in
>   the SQL Server Database.

Comment: login using domain admin account and add a new login for local account.

Answer (score 2):

I had to reread the vendor requirements a couple of times, but I take the instructions to mean the local administrator account only requires elevated permissions during installation.  Run one of the following blocks prior to the app install to set this up.

```
-- Add the Local Administrators Group
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [BUILTIN\Administrators]
GO

-- Or Add only the Local Administrator User - Dynamic SQL to capture servername
DECLARE @hostname NVARCHAR(128), @createStmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @hostname = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS NVARCHAR(128))

SET @createStmt = N'USE [master];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    N'CREATE LOGIN [' + @hostname + N'\Administrator] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    N'ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [' + @hostname + N'\Administrator];'

PRINT @createStmt
EXECUTE (@createStmt)
GO
```

When the installation is complete, be sure to back out these permissions as they are not the most secure, by running one of the following:

```
-- Drop Local Administrators group
USE [master]
GO
DROP LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators]
GO

-- Or Drop the explicitly defined Local Administrator login
DECLARE @hostname NVARCHAR(128), @createStmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @hostname = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS NVARCHAR(128))

SET @createStmt = N'USE [master];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    N'DROP LOGIN [' + @hostname + N'\Administrator];'

PRINT @createStmt
EXECUTE (@createStmt)
GO
```